# Why is it that one of my values in the dictionary is not being divided the same way and how would I fix it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a part of my code where the first function adds all the values in a dictionary and another function that divides each value from the overall value which means that the summary should all equal to 100 however I have this situation where the last value does not divide properly:

```
 dict = {'Cancelled': 31, 'Accepted': 145, 'Expired': 128, 'Rejected': 779}
 overall = 1083.0
 general_status_summary = {'Cancelled': 2.8624192059095108, 'Accepted': 13.745868405204407, 'Expired': 13.858688982866132, 'Rejected': 96.236168061830412}
```

As you can see, the rejected key is not correct but the other three are right. I am confuse as to why this is. Here is my code below:

```
 status_summary = statusSummary(2014, 04, 1, 2015, 03, 31)

    def overall(dict):
        overall_number = sum(dict.values())
        return float(overall_number)    

    overallstatus = overall(status_summary)

    def summaryPercentage(dict):
        for key, value in dict.items():
            dict[key] = (value/(overall(dict))) * 100
        return dict

    general_status_summary = summaryPercentage(status_summary)
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate

Comment: Don't recompute total while you modify the dict.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. Unmark it please

Comment: i don't think it i is a duplicate either, it has a sort of tangent but it doesn't address a solution

Comment: This is not caused by floating point weirdness. Not a duplicate.

Comment: The problem is not arithmetic, the problem is that each element is divided by different total.

Comment: @peaceandiago, you can change your summaryPercentage function like so: 

`def summaryPercentage(d):
    newDict = dict()
    for key, value in d.items():
        newDict[key] = (value/(overall(d))) * 100
    return newDict`

Comment: That was formatted terribly....

Comment: @Brian this is the right answer